# Port22:Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ssh, openssh, ubuntu-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQSuu.jpg)

## **I am still beginner with ubuntu servers and when l was trying to connect to server I got the error in image**

## I searched a lot about the problem to find solution but I didn't find anything help with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

the way ssh works you need to make sure the target machine is running sshd demon on port 22. (service)

The given topic is discussed in detail below thread.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2278

As per the thread, One of the prominent reasons the above issue is showing up is due to target firewall access at port 22 as well. Please check if such a filter exists.